# Is there an easy way to get a Manatee.JsonObject from a JSON string?

Tags: c#, manatee.json

We have a string that is JSON `{"value":1}` that we need to convert to a `Manatee.Json.JsonValue`.

Using `new JsonValue(value)` returns `"{\"value\":1}"` but we are looking for an actual JSON value of `{"value":1}`.

We have toyed with JsonObject, and it is possible by converting our JSON to a dictionary, but it would be nice if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `JsonValue.Parse()`.

From there you can get a `JsonObject` from the `.Object` property.  `JsonObject` is derived from `Dictionary<string, JsonValue>` so you should be able to do that conversation simply.

The documentation is linked on the GitHub readme at the top.

Comment: I swear I tried this earlier but I must have gotten confused, now I'm embarrassed that it's this easy. Thanks so much!